# Filter the file types to upload with ECMDocumentInfo - IBM BPM

Tags: ibm-bpm

How to limit the ability to load only certain types of files using the component(view) ECMDocumentInfo in a coach?
Is there some property to set?

IBM BPM 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.stbpm.doc/topics/tsec_config_docmanagement_security.html)? This may be what you are looking for. However, take into consideration that this configuration will apply to all the server (not only your coach view).

> **document-attachment-accepted-mime-types**
>   This option allows a whitelist of MIME types to be specified. MIME types included in the list will be allowed for upload, while all other MIME types will be blocked from upload.

Note: you may need at least the fix pack 8.5.0.2

Comment: mmm not praticable if the setting is shared server side. I have some coaches that accept excels, some other that acceprt pdfs and so on, thanks  anyway